# Save and retrieve the field value in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am modifying a plugin to implement additional fields and want to save details to wordpress options and then display the data on front end. Attached image
 [image: DropDown option]

Code implemented:

```
<!-- Host Status -->
            <td><select name='dropdown_settings[select_field_0]'>
    <option value='1' <?php selected( $options['select_field_0'], 1 ); ?>>Option 1</option>
    <option value='2' <?php selected( $options['select_field_0'], 2 ); ?>>Option 2</option>
    <option value='3' <?php selected( $options['select_field_0'], 3 ); ?>>Option 3</option>
    <option value='4' <?php selected( $options['select_field_0'], 4 ); ?>>Option 4</option>
</select></td>
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing to implement this? Because you haven't mention your query.

Comment: i want to save data (status value) using ajax.

Comment: You can check how that plugin save the fields data and using that you can do it. Moreover you can stored extra field values in update_post_meta and can retrieve using get_post_meta function

Comment: What keeps you from saving the data using AJAX?